# Calculating amount of time during day and night using date_sunrise() and date_sunset() php

Tags: php, date-sunrise

I am trying to calculate the amount of hours during the day and during the night using the sunrise and sunset times returned by the date_sunrise() and the date_sunset() functions. Admittedly though I'm not really sure how to go about doing that. I thought that making the sunrise and sunset times into variables and subtracting from each other might work, but I didn't take into consideration that subtracting hours is different than subtracting regular numbers, haha.

```
        $lat = 38.7;
        $long = -75;
        $sunrise = (date_sunrise(time(),SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING,38.7,-75,75,-5));
        $sunset = (date_sunset(time(),SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING,38.7,-75,75,-5));
        //$light = $sunset - $sunrise; <-- Should return hours of daylight
        //$dark =  <-- Should return hours of nighttime

        echo "Date: " . date("D M j Y");
        echo "<br>Latitude: " . $lat;
        echo "<br>Longitude: " . $long . "<br>";

        echo "<br>Sunrise Time: " . $sunrise; 
        echo "<br>Sunset Time: " . $sunset . "<br>";

        echo "<br>Hours of Light: " . $light;
        echo "<br>Hours of Dark: " . $dark;
        ?>
```

This is what I have in terms of code so far. Everything else works fine, I just need to figure out the $light and $dark variables. Any assistance would be much appreciated!

expected result should be something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvlij.png)

Thank you!